# DateTime ParseExact exception

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
var str = "00:00:00 02/01/1990";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

The above code is throwing an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I thought using ParseExact and specifying the exact format this would be okay. What is wrong with the above?

EDIT:

Solved using invariant culture. Thanks for comments.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what framework version were you targeting? Seems to work for 4.0

Comment: The : and / characters are substituted by the time and date separation characters for the local culture, even for ParseExact().  You thus must specify a culture to get reproducible results, like invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes usually in `DateTime` format the `Date` comes first before `Time`. Try this out:

```
var str = "02/01/1990 00:00:00";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

**EDITED:** OK so you do one trick to get it done:

```
var str = "00:00:00 02/01/1990";
var split = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
if (split.Length == 2)
    str = String.Format("{0} {1}", split[1], split[0]);
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: The program is importing data from a csv file. In the csv file the format is "00:00:00 02/01/1990" rather than "02/01/1990 00:00:00". Which is why I need to use the format specified above.

Answer (score 1):

The "hh" format specifier is for 12-hour AM/PM time, which doesn't support a "00". Try defining it in 24-hour time: `HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: I get the same error with HH, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."